# Kubernetes NodePort not working correctly

Tags: docker, nginx, curl, kubernetes

I have a cluster Kubernetes cluster on a local machine and one raspberry pi. In order to test the cluster I created a nginx deployment and a service that I want to access as a NodePort. But for God know's why, I can't access said service. Bellow are my deployment and service files.

`kubectl get nodes`

```
NAME      STATUS                        ROLES    AGE    VERSION
anima     Ready                         master   7d5h   v1.16.1
bahamut   Ready                         <none>   7d4h   v1.16.1
```

My service and deployment files:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: nginx:latest
        resources:
          limits:
            memory: "128Mi"
            cpu: "500m"
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
      nodeSelector:
        kubernetes.io/hostname: bahamut
```

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: nginx
spec:
  selector:
    app: nginx
  ports:
  - port: 3030
    targetPort: 80
  type: NodePort
```

After `kubectl get pods -o wide`:

```
NAME                     READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE     IP            NODE      NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES
nginx-67c8c4b564-6x7g5   1/1     Running   0          6m21s   10.244.1.13   bahamut   <none>           <none>
```

My Deployments, `kubectl get deployments -o wide`:

```
NAME    READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE     CONTAINERS   IMAGES         SELECTOR
nginx   1/1     1            1           7m55s   nginx        nginx:latest   app=nginx
```

My Services, `kubectl get svc -o wide`:

```
NAME         TYPE        CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)          AGE     SELECTOR
kubernetes   ClusterIP   10.96.0.1       <none>        443/TCP          7d5h    <none>
nginx        NodePort    10.102.203.77   <none>        3030:30508/TCP   8m54s   app=nginx
```

And finally, `kubectl get endpoints -o wide`:

```
NAME         ENDPOINTS           AGE
kubernetes   192.168.25.4:6443   7d5h
nginx        10.244.1.13:80      9m41s
```

My Kubernetes master local IP is `192.168.25.4` and my raspberry ip is `192.168.25.6`. After deploying the service I tried:

```
curl 192.168.25.6:3030
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 192.168.25.6 port 3030: Connection refused

curl 192.168.25.6:80
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 192.168.25.6 port 80: Connection refused

curl 192.168.25.6:30508 (hangs)
```

Also tried using the master node IP, the Service IP and the listed Cluster IP, but nothing works.

**EDIT**

It works if I use `hostNetwork=true` on the deployment and access it using the node local IP on the container port, but obviously that's not what I want. I want to understand why Kubernetes isn't let me access the container through the service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the flannel interface. After a `ip link delete flannel.1` and restarting flannel pods, the service started to work flawlessly.

Answer (score 4):

NodePort exposes the Service on each Node’s IP at a static port (the NodePort) in your case it is `30508`. Please see more details [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#publishing-services-service-types).

And [this](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/baremetal/) will share more details on the bare-metal clusters.

Answer (score 2):

The `port` should be the value of the port exposed by the service, `80`.

If you want to keep the node port fixed to an specific value, change your service to something like:

```
  - port: 80
    nodePort: 30030
```

please note that the node port range is `30000 - 32767`
after that you should be able to query:

```
curl <node>:30030
```